# Twitter bootstrap grids bug on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to integrate twitter bootstrap (v3) into a small site I'm currently building but I'm seeing a bug in the grids on iPad (landscape mode) whereby the columns total 12 but don't seem to line up on the right hand-side.

I thought maybe I'd added some CSS that may have been affecting the grids styling but having gone back to the twitter bootstrap documentation I'm actually seeing the same bug right there (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

I was just wondering if anyone else had come across this same problem and if so whether they'd found a fix?

*I've added a red line highlighting the issue in the image below.  The row of twelve **.col-md-1** don't seem to add up to the width of the other rows!?!?*

[image: Twitter bootstrap grids bug on iPad]

Answer (score 2):

I created a solution here that I want you to check out, please post back on the GitHub page instead of here. Also, please vote this up so others can find it.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10723#issuecomment-25134475

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are the one who asked this question on github but for others who stumble upon this question it appears to be a safari rounding issue. Will update later.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10723

> This is presumably the "Safari percent rounding" problem mentioned in
>   our docs: http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started/#browsers
>   Although this is the first report we've gotten of it happening on iOS
>   Safari. Guess we need to update the docs in that regard.

This appears to be true. I did a quick test trying out a different col widths and as you get more columns the amount of white space increase (more rounding errors).

Check this out on your ipad in landscape:

http://hajimefurukawa.com/random/code/row-ipad.html